# How to match nearest tag backward with XPath

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a HTML like this:

```
html =<<EOS
<table><!-- outer table -->
  <tr><td>
    <table><!-- inner table 1 -->
      <tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
    </table>
    <table><!-- inner table 2 -->
      <tr><td>Bar</td></tr>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
</table>
EOS
```

I want to get a changing value `Bar` from a static value `Foo`.

With this code I can get the value.

```
Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.xpath("//table[tr/td[text()='Foo']]/following-sibling::table//td").text
```

And I wanted to rewrite like this:

```
doc.xpath("//table[//td[text()='Foo']]/following-sibling::table//td").text
```

But this code doesn't work because `//table[//td[text()='Foo']]` matches outer table not the inner table.

Is there a expression for `nearest backward match` in XPath like this?

`//table[(nearest match expression)td[text()='Foo']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `//table[//td[text()='Foo']]` gives the outer table as the first result (not the only result) , but `//table[//td[text()='Foo']]/following-sibling::table//td` still retrieves `<td>Bar</td>`.

The problematic part of `//table[//td[text()='Foo']]` is the `//` in front of `td`, because it selects all descendant `td` elements:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This is selected</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>This is also selected</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You should use `//` only sparingly. I would use the expression

```
//table[tr/td = 'Foo']/following-sibling::table[1]/tr/td
```

---

**EDIT**: As suggested by Phrogz, in Nokogiri, instead of `[1]` in the expression above, you can use `at_xpath` as in

```
doc.at_xpath(//table[tr/td = 'Foo']/following-sibling::table/tr/td).text
```

to only get the first result node that was found. That is, if you actually intend to only find one node and if the wanted node is the first one in document order.

Comment: Using `my_doc.at` or `my_doc.at_xpath` you can remove the `[1]` from the XPath, correct?

Comment: @Phrogz Probably, is that Ruby syntax? What does it mean?

Comment: Using Nokogiri the `at` and `at_xpath` methods will return only the first matching element instead of a collection of nodes.

Comment: @Phrogz Yes, if you actually _want_ to get one result only and if the first result is the wanted one. But thanks for the hint, I'll add this to the answer.